# How to track path/key during recursion through hash of hashes in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, loops, recursion, hash

I've been trying to compare two hashes of hashes against each other. Unfortunately even with the great help from here I struggled to pull together what I was trying to do.

So, I've resorted to searching the internet again and I was lucky enough to find Edxi's code (full credit to him and Dbroeglin who looks to have written it originally)

https://gist.github.com/edxi/87cb8a550b43ec90e4a89d2e69324806

His compare-hash function does exactly what I needed in terms of its comparisons. However, I'd like to report of the full path of the hash in the final output. So I've tried to update the code to allow for this. My thinking being that I should be able to take the Key (aka path) while the code loops over itself but I'm clearly going about it in the wrong manner.

Am I going about this with the right approach, and if not, would someone suggest another method please? The biggest problem I've found so far is that if I change the hash, my code changes don't work e.g. adding `'More' = 'stuff'` So it becomes `$sailings.Arrivals.PDH083.More` breaks the path in the way I've set it.

My version of the code:

```
$Sailings = @{
    'Arrivals'   = @{
        'PDH083' = @{
            'GoingTo'   = 'Port1'
            'Scheduled' = '09:05'
            'Expected'  = '10:11'
            'Status'    = 'Delayed'
        }
    }
    'Departures' = @{
        'PDH083' = @{
            'ArrivingFrom' = 'Port1'
            'Scheduled'    = '09:05'
            'Expected'     = '09:05'
            'Status'       = 'OnTime'
            'Other'        = @{'Data' = 'Test'}
        }
    }
}

$Flights = @{
    'Arrivals'   = @{
        'PDH083' = @{
            'GoingTo'   = 'Port'
            'Scheduled' = '09:05'
            'Expected'  = '10:20'
            'Status'    = 'Delayed'

        }
    }
    'Departures' = @{
        'PDH083' = @{
            'ArrivingFrom' = 'Port11'
            'Scheduled'    = '09:05'
            'Expected'     = '09:05'
            'Status'       = 'NotOnTime'
            'Other'        = @{'Data' = 'Test_Diff'}
        }
    }
}


function Compare-Hashtable {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [Hashtable]$Left,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [Hashtable]$Right,
        [string] $path,
        [boolean] $trackpath = $True
    )
    write-host "PAth received as: $path"
    function New-Result($Key, $LValue, $Side, $RValue) {
        New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
            key    = $Key
            lvalue = $LValue
            rvalue = $RValue
            side   = $Side
        }
    }




    [Object[]]$Results = $Left.Keys | ForEach-Object {

        if ($trackpath ) {
            write-host "Working on Path: " $path + $_
        }

        if ($Left.ContainsKey($_) -and !$Right.ContainsKey($_)) {
            write-host "Right key not matched. Report path as: $path"
            New-Result $path $Left[$_] "<=" $Null
        }
        else {
            if ($Left[$_] -is [hashtable] -and $Right[$_] -is [hashtable] ) {
                if ($path -ne $null -or $path -ne "/") {
                    $path = $path + "/" + $_
                    write-host "Sending Path to function as: $path"
                }
                Compare-Hashtable $Left[$_] $Right[$_] $path
            }
            else {
                $LValue, $RValue = $Left[$_], $Right[$_]
                if ($LValue -ne $RValue) {
                    $path = $path + "/" + $_
                    write-host "Not a hash so must be a value at path:$path"
                    New-Result $path $LValue "!=" $RValue
                }
                else {
                    Write-Host "Before changing path: $path "
                    if (($path.Substring(0, $path.lastIndexOf('/'))).length >0) {
                        $path = $path.Substring(0, $path.lastIndexOf('/'))
                        Write-Host "After changing path: $path "
                    }
                }
            }

        }
       # if (($path.Substring(0, $path.lastIndexOf('/'))).length >0) { 
       # Tried to use this to stop error on substring being less than zero
       # but clearly doesnt work when you add more levels to the hash 
                   $path = $path.Substring(0, $path.lastIndexOf('/'))
       # } else { $path = $path.Substring(0, $path.lastIndexOf('/')) }

    }



    $Results += $Right.Keys | ForEach-Object {
        if (!$Left.ContainsKey($_) -and $Right.ContainsKey($_)) {
            New-Result $_ $Null "=>" $Right[$_]

        }
    }


    if ($Results -ne $null) { $Results }
}
cls

Compare-Hashtable $Sailings $Flights

outputs
key                             lvalue side rvalue
---                             ------ ---- ------
/Arrivals/PDH083/Expected       10:11  !=   10:20
/Arrivals/GoingTo               Port1  !=   Port
/Departures/PDH083/ArrivingFrom Port1  !=   Port11
/Departures/PDH083/Status       OnTime !=   NotOnTime
/Departures/PDH083/Other/Data   Test   !=   Test_Diff
```

Comment: You can also see that my code looses the PDH083 key on the Arrivals/GoingTo output. So, clearly I am tackling this in the wrong manner.

Comment: Thanks @halfer for editing the question. Apologies, I'll reframe from posting unnecessary commentary in future. As for the standard of my English, well I tried my best, but I guess it’s a good as my coding abilities.

Comment: Your English seems excellent to me! `:-)` Yes, we like things succinct here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't do that much string manipulation on the `$Path` but threat `$Path` as an array and join it to a string at the moment you assign it as a property (`key = $Path -Join "/"`) to the object:

```
function Compare-Hashtable {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [Hashtable]$Left,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [Hashtable]$Right,
        [string[]] $path = @(),
        [boolean] $trackpath = $True
    )
    write-host "Path received as: $path"
    function New-Result($Path, $LValue, $Side, $RValue) {
        New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
            key    = $Path -Join "/"
            lvalue = $LValue
            rvalue = $RValue
            side   = $Side
        }
    }

    $Left.Keys | ForEach-Object {
        $NewPath = $Path + $_
        if ($trackpath ) {
            write-host "Working on Path: " $NewPath
        }

        if ($Left.ContainsKey($_) -and !$Right.ContainsKey($_)) {
            write-host "Right key not matched. Report path as: $NewPath"
            New-Result $NewPath $Left[$_] "<=" $Null
        }
        else {
            if ($Left[$_] -is [hashtable] -and $Right[$_] -is [hashtable] ) {
                 Compare-Hashtable $Left[$_] $Right[$_] $NewPath
            }
            else {
                $LValue, $RValue = $Left[$_], $Right[$_]
                if ($LValue -ne $RValue) {
                    New-Result $NewPath $LValue "!=" $RValue
                }
             }

        }
    }
    $Right.Keys | ForEach-Object {
        $NewPath = $Path + $_
        if (!$Left.ContainsKey($_) -and $Right.ContainsKey($_)) {
            New-Result $NewPath $Null "=>" $Right[$_]

        }
    }
}
cls

Compare-Hashtable $Sailings $Flights
```

*side-note:* **Write Single Records to the Pipeline (SC03)**, see: [Strongly Encouraged Development Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd878270(v=vs.85).aspx#SC03). In other words, don't do the `$Results += ...` but intermediately put any completed result in the pipeline for the next cmdlet to be picked up (besides, it unnecessarily code)...

Comment: thank you so much! You've managed to do that so simply. Couldn't have got further from where my mind had gone. Thank you also for your side comment. I'll actually be using this as a call within another section of code. Would your recommendation still apply if its not being used as part of a cmdlet? I've not come across the Cmdlet.WriteObject method before, so I'll have to spend some time reading up on it. Do you know of any example that demonstrate its use?

Comment: Sorry @iRon, Just thought of another question. Is there a way to trap the name of the actual hash that was sent to the function e.g. $Flights would give the name Flights? 
My thinking for needing this is the difference could be on Left or Right hash. So I should really record the name of the calling hash or is it easier to change the data structure to have a new parent level so its $hashone.Sailings or $hashtwo.flights that way its always clear?

Comment: manged to re-read the information on Write Single Records to the Pipeline (SC03), understand it better now. If I have understood correctly its not an additional method/command more a case of just letting the objects return back. instead of queuing them, to then return them in mass. Hopefully my understanding is now correct.

Comment: You understanding is correct: presume that your input tables come from a slow provider and that your output goes to another slow provider, PowerShell can start releasing data to the output provider while it is still pulling information from the input provider...

Comment: I am quite sure you can't retrieve the original names as `$Sailings` and `$Flights`.